# Making a density argument work

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

A homework problem I have is to show that $1/N \sum_{n=1}^N f(n\alpha) \to \int_\mathbb{T} f dx$ for any $\alpha$ irrational, and $f$ lebesgue integrable.

I understand why this is true for $f$ continuous because we can approximate it uniformly by trigonometric polynomials.

My density argument, to try to make this hold for Lebesgue integrable functions, in the last comment is boiling down to controlling the term
$1/N \sum_{n \text{ from 1 to N s.t. } n\alpha \in E_\delta^c} |f_m(n\alpha) -f(n\alpha)|$

as $\delta \to 0$ and $N\to \infty$.  Here $E^c$ is a set of measure 0(lebesgue points) s.t. $f$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E$ and $E_\delta^c$ are sets of measure less than $\delta$ such that on $E_\delta, f_m \to f$ uniformly.

EDIT:  I took out what follows because it made it unclear what I was asking.  I was trying to do some special cases but I think what I have above is clearer.
EDIT to an edit:  I think what I am asking to prove is false.

---

I am trying to figure out why this holds for a piecewise continuous function like $x$ on $[0,1]$ extended periodically.  For this I figured out two routes to proceed:  Show that 
$1/N \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{k=l}^\infty i/(2\pi k) e^{2\pi i k\alpha n}$ tends to 0 as $N$ tends to infinity.

Alternatively I need to show that $\sum_{n \text{  s.t. } n \alpha \in [0,\epsilon) \cup (1-\epsilon,1]} i/(2\pi n) e^{2\pi i \alpha n} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: I know where you are taking me with this.

Comment: You are trying to tell me that  $|1/N \sum_{n=1}^N e^(2 \pi i \alpha n)|=1/N\frac{1-e^{2 \pi i \alpha N}}{1-e^{2 \pi i \alpha}}  \leq 2/(N|1-e^{2 \pi i \alpha|) \to 0$

Comment: no I didn't understand your question in fact, you are talking of 4 different problems, not obviously related, and you didn't say clearly for which one  you really want an answer. and in the last one, you meant $n\alpha$ modulo $1 \in \ldots$ ?

Comment: I am sorry.  Thanks for taking the time to help me.   I am trying to figure out a special case of my homework.  I reduced this to showing what comes after 'alternatively'.  Let me put more details in the question so that is clear how I reduced the homework problem to this. (The point is that you have uniform convergence of some trigonometric polynomials to the periodic extension of $x$ outside $[0,\epsilon) \cup (1-\epsilon ,1]$)

Comment: hence, once you proved it for continuous functions, you also proved it for $f \in L^1([0,1])$ if there exists a sequence of continuous functions $(f_m)_m$ such that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \|f-f_m\|_{L^1([0,1])} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \int_0^1 |f(x)-f_m(x) |dx = 0$

Comment: taking the Fourier series side, you should consider adding a regularization term to make it convergent. don't forget that the Fourier series are often  not converging to the function, but if $\|f\|^2_{L^2([0,1]} = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$ then $\|f -f_N\|_{L^2([0,1])} \to 0$ when $N \to \infty$, with $f_N(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n x} e^{-n^2 / N^2}$ the regularized (filtered) Fourier series (which is a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions converging to $f$, hence useful for applying what I wrote above)

Comment: In both of these cases you are finding different ways to approximate $f$ by in the first comment are  continuous functions and the second comment are functions in $\mathbb{A}(\mathbb{T})$.  This is done presumably so that the work is left to a density argument.  My trouble is that the density argument is not working as it should.  It is involving what I have after 'alternatively' in my question.

Comment: First naively we have $|1/N \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n\alpha) - \int_\mathbb{T} f| \leq 1/N  |\sum_{n=1}^N |f_m(n\alpha)-f(n\alpha)|+|1/N \sum_{n=1}^N f_m(n\alpha)-\int_\mathbb{T} f_m |+|\int (f_m-f)| \leq 1/N  |\sum_{n=1}^N |f_m-f|_\infty+|1/N \sum_{n=1}^N f_m(n\alpha)-\int_\mathbb{T} f_m |+\int |f_m-f|$

Comment: Since $f_m$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly we then take $E_\delta$ s.t. egorov's theorem gives us that $\chi_{E_\delta}f_m $ converges uniformly to $\chi_{E_\delta} f$. Our sum is less than  $\leq 1/N  \sum_{n=1}^N |f_m-f|_{L^\infty(E_\delta)}+1/N \sum_{n \text{ from 1 to N s.t. } n\alpha \in E_\delta^c} |f_m(n\alpha) -f(n\alpha)|+|1/N \sum_{n=1}^N f_m(n\alpha)-\int_\mathbb{T} f_m |+\int |f_m-f|$.  But now I am stuck with trying to control the term $1/N \sum_{n \text{ from 1 to N s.t. } n\alpha \in E_\delta^c} |f_m(n\alpha) -f(n\alpha)|$.

Comment: This term that I am trying to control in this density argument is exactly the term I have after 'alternatively' in my post.